# A Better way to optimize these MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have two MySQL tables:

- attributes (attributeid, name)
- productsattributes (productid, attributeid, displayvalue)

The required is for each attribute name called "Product Type" get all other attributes associated with this "Product Type". As an example — attributes table will look like:

```
    attributeid  name
    1            A
    2            B
    3            Product Type
    4            D
```

productsattributes table will look like:

```
productid attributeid displayvalue
        1         3           FAN
        1         1           Brown
        1         2           Stand
        2         3           FAN
        2         4           D
        3         3           CAR
        3         4           imported
```

So the final result should be:

```
FAN (A,B, Product Type,D) 
CAR (Product Type, imported)
```

Here is my try:

- first I get all the "displayvalues" from productattributes:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT displayvalue 
  FROM productsttributes 
 WHERE attributeid = 3;
```

- then I loop through each "displayvalues" to find the other attributes:

```sql
SELECT a.name 
 FROM attributes a 
 INNER JOIN productsattributes pa 
    ON pa.attributeid = a.attributeid AND productid in (
        SELECT productid 
        FROM productsttributes 
        WHERE dispalyvale =  '$displayvalue') 
 ORDER BY a.name;
```

The problem is the productattributes table has about 7 million rows, so my script is taking forever .. of course I am not looking for 10 minutes solution but at least it will improve my queries a bit.

Comment: does displayvalue have an index?

Comment: Nope, only productid, attributeid.

Comment: I also don't understand how you want to join multiple products together - I understand that product 1 and 2 are both fans, but should they be combined (as in your example)?

Comment: Yes, they are different products but they share the same "Product Type" which is FAN, now for FAN I need to get all other attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with the following statements:

```sql
ALTER TABLE attributes ADD CONSTRAINT p_attributes PRIMARY KEY (attributeid);
ALTER TABLE productsattributes ADD CONSTRAINT p_productsattributes
    PRIMARY KEY(productid, attributeid);
ANALYZE TABLE attributes, productsattributes;
```

This will make sure all important fields are indexed.

The query might look like this (also on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39600/3)):

```sql
SELECT trg.displayvalue,
       group_concat(a.name ORDER BY trg.productid, a.attributeid)
  FROM (
        SELECT t.productid,t.displayvalue
          FROM attributes a
          JOIN productsattributes t USING (attributeid)
         WHERE a.name = 'Product Type') AS trg
  JOIN productsattributes p ON p.productid = trg.productid
  JOIN attributes a ON a.attributeid = p.attributeid
 GROUP BY trg.displayvalue
 ORDER BY 1;
```

Please, kindly include the `EXPLAIN` output of your's and this queries into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
Select displayvalue, attribute_name
from 
(Select 
product_id from productsattributes pa inner join attributes_table at on (pa.attributeid=at.id) where at.name=?) as productList
inner join  productsattributes pa2 on(pa2.product_id=productList.product_id)
inner join attributes_table at2 on (pa2.attributeid=at2.id)
```